# How do I dynamically populate a drop-down list in install4j?

Tags: install4j

I am having trouble figuring out how to populate a drop-down list on a form in install4j.  I have custom code which returns a String[], and sets a variable to this value.  That is working correctly.

For the help for the drop-down and combo box components, it says the following:

> The items in the drop-down list as a list separated by semicolons. The
>   items in the list must be separated by semicolons followed by a space.
>   If you click on the edit button in the property editor, you can enter
>   one item per line in a separate dialog. Items that are installer
>   variables with array values (e.g. String[], Object[] or File[]) are
>   expanded as separate items, this allows you to build a variable length
>   list of items at runtime.

This would imply that adding my installer variable in the items list is all I need to do.  But this appears as literal text.  Should I be setting the list options with code instead?

See: http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If an installer variable named "listItems" is set to

```
new String[] {"One", "Two", "Three"}
```

and the "Drop-down list entries" property of the "Drop-down list" form component is set to

```
${installer:listItems}
```

then the drop-down list will have three entries.

Comment: Thanks Ingo - I thought that should have worked - it was a typo on my part, I was using `${installer.variable}` rather than `${installer:variable}`.

Comment: Is it possible to change the value of dropdownlist? when binding the component to installer runtime variable, the value returned is the index position of the selected value... Is there any way to change that?

Comment: when using the dropdown values edit dialog box, if I use the (pipe symbol) | , hoping it'd set the `key|value` pair, but it didn't

Comment: So I changed it to a Combo box... But that gives the users to edit the value... and that in-turn might introduce new bugs... and return unpredictable results... Is there any clear subtle solution?

Comment: @CrystalPaladin To edit multiple values, use the property editor ("..." button on the right side) and enter one value per line. The variable value of a drop-down form component is the index, as of 7.0 there is no way to change this.

Comment: good to know... Also I've checked out the other selection controls and they all return selected index instead of text. Now I'm finding a way to disable editing on the Combobox's text region... to achieve the goal... Anyway, Install4j is so flexible... I love it... you guys keep up the good work...